# Вертикальное меню. У родителя псевдокласс, нужно убрать ему высоту, равную высоте последнего ребенка

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Имеется вот такая менюха:

```js
$(".collection-menu > li .item-link").click(function () {
  $(this).parent('.collection-menu > li').find('.sub-menu').slideToggle("200");
  $(this).find('.icon i').toggleClass('rotate-icon');
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('active-item');  
});
```

```css
.collection-menu {
  width: 220px;
  
  
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
}
.collection-menu:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: -1px;
  height: calc(100% - 17px);
  width: 2px;
  border-left: 2px dashed #d3d3d3;
}


.collection-menu > li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.collection-menu > li:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}
.collection-menu > li:before {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  top: -2px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #cecece;
  transition: all .5s;
  z-index: 2;
}
.collection-menu .favorite:before {
  content: '\f004';
  left: -36px;
}
.collection-menu .design:before {
  content: '\f111';
  left: -35px;
}
.collection-menu .illustration:before {
  content: '\f111';
  left: -35px;
}

/* ======================== Arrow-right animation ======================== */
.collection-menu > li .item-link {
  display: flex;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.collection-menu > li > .item-link span:first-child {
  transition: 300ms; 
}
.collection-menu > li > .item-link .icon {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 15px;
  transition: all .5s;
}
.collection-menu > li > .item-link .icon i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s;
}
.collection-menu > li > .item-link:hover .icon i {
  left: calc(100% - 20px);
  opacity: 1;
}
.collection-menu > li > .item-link .item-title .subitems-number {
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: #1bb1a5;
}

.rotate-icon {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  left: calc(100% - 20px) !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transition: all .25s;
}
.collection-menu > li.active-item:before {
  color: #bd10e0;
  transition: all 1s;
}
/* ======================== Arrow-right animation ======================== */

.collection-menu .sub-menu {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.collection-menu .sub-menu li {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.collection-menu .sub-menu li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: -20px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 2px;
  border-top: 2px dashed #cecece;
}
.collection-menu .sub-menu li a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.collection-menu .sub-menu li:first-child a {
  color: #1bb1a5;
}
.user-bookmark .user-title {
  margin: 0;
}

/* ---------- Animation for new bookmark ----------- */
.new-bookmark {
  animation: opacityslow 1s;
  transition: 1s;
}
@keyframes opacityslow {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1}
}
/* ---------- Animation for new bookmark ----------- */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-iconic-font/2.2.0/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ea0959dcb8.js"></script>
<ul class="collection-menu">
  <li class="favorite">
    <a href="#close" class="item-link">
      <span class="item-title">Favorites<span class="subitems-number">1</span></span>
      <span class="icon"><i class="zmdi zmdi-arrow-right"></i></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="add-bookmarks">
        <a href="#close">Add bookmarks <i class="zmdi zmdi-plus"></i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="design">
    <a href="#close" class="item-link">
      <span class="item-title">Design<span class="subitems-number">1</span></span>
      <span class="icon"><i class="zmdi zmdi-arrow-right"></i></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="add-bookmarks">
        <a href="#close">Add bookmarks <i class="zmdi zmdi-plus"></i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
    <li class="illustration">
    <a href="#close" class="item-link">
      <span class="item-title">Illustration<span class="subitems-number">1</span></span>
      <span class="icon"><i class="zmdi zmdi-arrow-right"></i></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="add-bookmarks">
        <a href="#close">Add bookmarks <i class="zmdi zmdi-plus"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="user-bookmarks">
        <h4 class="bookmark-title">Articles about some especial and wonderfull</h4>
        <p class="bookmark-descr">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Все отлично, но есть одна большая проблема, решение которой я сам не нашел, поэтому обращаюсь за помощью к вам.

**Собственно, сабж:** если развернуть последний пункт меню, вы увидите, что вертикальная пунктирная линия отображается не так как следует - она должна кончаться на последнем пункте (в данном случае на заголовке закладки "Articles about some especial and wonderfull") вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли какие-то идеи, как привести в порядок менюшку?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/x1wpoecx/

Comment: вариант на css - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/8myd9d29/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ваш вариант**

```js
$(".collection-menu > li .item-link").click(function () {
  $(this).parent('.collection-menu > li').find('.sub-menu').slideToggle("200");
  $(this).find('.icon i').toggleClass('rotate-icon');
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('active-item');  
});
```

```css
.collection-menu {
  width: 220px;  
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
}
.collection-menu > li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.collection-menu > li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 10px; left: -26px;
  height: calc(100% + 25px);
  width: 2px;
  border-left: 2px dashed #d3d3d3;
}
.collection-menu > li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;    
}
.collection-menu > li:last-child:after {  
  height: 0;
}
.collection-menu > li:last-child .sub-menu > li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: -20px; left: -26px;
  height: calc(100% + 15px);
  width: 2px;
  border-left: 2px dashed #d3d3d3;
}
.collection-menu > li:last-child .sub-menu > li:last-child:after{  
  height: 29px;
}

.collection-menu > li:before {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  top: -2px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #cecece;
  transition: all .5s;
  z-index: 2;
}
.collection-menu .favorite:before {
  content: '\f004';
  left: -36px;
}
.collection-menu .design:before {
  content: '\f111';
  left: -35px;
}
.collection-menu .illustration:before {
  content: '\f111';
  left: -35px;
}

/* ======================== Arrow-right animation ======================== */
.collection-menu > li .item-link {
  display: flex;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.collection-menu > li > .item-link span:first-child {
  transition: 300ms; 
}
.collection-menu > li > .item-link .icon {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 15px;
  transition: all .5s;
}
.collection-menu > li > .item-link .icon i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s;
}
.collection-menu > li > .item-link:hover .icon i {
  left: calc(100% - 20px);
  opacity: 1;
}
.collection-menu > li > .item-link .item-title .subitems-number {
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: #1bb1a5;
}

.rotate-icon {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  left: calc(100% - 20px) !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transition: all .25s;
}
.collection-menu > li.active-item:before {
  color: #bd10e0;
  transition: all 1s;
}
/* ======================== Arrow-right animation ======================== */

.collection-menu .sub-menu {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.collection-menu .sub-menu li {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.collection-menu .sub-menu li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: -20px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 2px;
  border-top: 2px dashed #cecece;
}
.collection-menu .sub-menu li a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.collection-menu .sub-menu li:first-child a {
  color: #1bb1a5;
}
.user-bookmark .user-title {
  margin: 0;
}

/* ---------- Animation for new bookmark ----------- */
.new-bookmark {
  animation: opacityslow 1s;
  transition: 1s;
}
@keyframes opacityslow {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1}
}
/* ---------- Animation for new bookmark ----------- */
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ea0959dcb8.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-iconic-font/2.2.0/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="collection-menu">
  <li class="favorite">
    <a href="#close" class="item-link">
      <span class="item-title">Favorites<span class="subitems-number">1</span></span>
      <span class="icon"><i class="zmdi zmdi-arrow-right"></i></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="add-bookmarks">
        <a href="#close">Add bookmarks <i class="zmdi zmdi-plus"></i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="design">
    <a href="#close" class="item-link">
      <span class="item-title">Design<span class="subitems-number">1</span></span>
      <span class="icon"><i class="zmdi zmdi-arrow-right"></i></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="add-bookmarks">
        <a href="#close">Add bookmarks <i class="zmdi zmdi-plus"></i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
    <li class="illustration">
    <a href="#close" class="item-link">
      <span class="item-title">Illustration<span class="subitems-number">1</span></span>
      <span class="icon"><i class="zmdi zmdi-arrow-right"></i></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="add-bookmarks">
        <a href="#close">Add bookmarks <i class="zmdi zmdi-plus"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="user-bookmarks">
        <h4 class="bookmark-title">Articles about some especial and wonderfull</h4>
        <p class="bookmark-descr">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Вариант на css**

```css
body{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.b-menu {
  max-width: 220px;
  margin: 15px auto;  
}
.b-menu > li{
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding-left: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.b-menu > li:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 11px;    
  width: 2px;
  height: calc(100% + 40px);
  border-left: 2px dashed #ccc;
}
.b-menu > li:last-child:after{
  height: 0;
}



[id^=menu-]{
  display: none;
}
[id^=menu-] + label{
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
}

[id^=menu-] + label:before,
[id^=menu-] + label:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: -3px; left: -40px;  
  z-index: 5;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;  
  border-radius: 50%;
}
[id^=menu-] + label:before{
  background: #ccc;
}
[id^=menu-] + label:after{   
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #800080;  
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
}
[id^=menu-]:checked + label:after{  
  opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

[id^=menu-] + label:hover{
  color: green;
}
[id^=menu-]:checked + label{
  color: #800080;
}

#menu-1:checked + label ~ .b-submenu-1,
#menu-2:checked + label ~ .b-submenu-2,
#menu-3:checked + label ~ .b-submenu-3{
  max-height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.b-submenu{
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;  
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  transition: 0.6s;
}
.b-submenu > li{
  margin: 10px 0;  
  position: relative;
}
.b-submenu > li > a{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.b-submenu > li:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 10px; left: -35px;    
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  border-top: 2px dashed #ccc;
}
.b-menu > li:last-child [id^=menu-] + label ~ .b-submenu > li:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: -38px;
  height: 0; 
  width: 2px;
  border-left: 2px dashed #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.b-menu > li:last-child [id^=menu-]:checked + label ~ .b-submenu > li:after{
  height: calc(100% + 10px); 
}
.b-menu > li:last-child [id^=menu-]:checked + label ~ .b-submenu > li:last-child:after{  
  height: 11px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="b-menu">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu-1" name="m" />
    <label for="menu-1">menu 1</label>
    <ul class="b-submenu b-submenu-1">
      <li><a href="#">submenu 1.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu 1.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu 1.3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu-2" name="m" />
    <label for="menu-2">menu 2</label>
    <ul class="b-submenu b-submenu-2">
      <li><a href="#">submenu 2.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu 2.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu 2.3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu-3" name="m" />
    <label for="menu-3">menu 3</label>
    <ul class="b-submenu b-submenu-3">
      <li><a href="#">submenu 3.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu 3.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu 3.3</a>
      <p> text text text text text text</p>  
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

ну как минимум не нужно цеплять бордер .collection-menu:before
его нужно цеплять к лишкам
.collection-menu > li
и регулировать высоту на последней лишке используя :last-child (размер падинга и line-height для заголовка мы знаем)